What happens to refugees after their country is no longer considered unsafe?
With for example Syria, the refugees fleeing the Assad regime which has now fallen, who claimed asylum in Europe because of war, what will happen to them if the country will be considered safe to return, or safe that no new refugees are to be accepted?
Will these refugees start to be deported? What is their legal status considered?
Or for example political refugees from Russia fleeing to the west, what will happen to them in the case of regime change of Putin?

For some, the new regime in Syria may also be unsafe. Before a new regime is established, it is too soon to know.  For example, Christian refugees will continue to be refugees under the convention definition if a government arises that declares itself dedicated to the elimination of Christianity in Syria.

Two things:  first of all, it is premature to say that Syria will be safe in the near/mid term future.  Second, one can easily guess that, in 2024, many political parties in Western Europe will try their hardest to avoid a repeat of the answer given in the duplicate question, which can be summarized as "well, not all that much", despite that region having become reasonably safe.

It might also be a miscalculation by refugee right campaigners, to overreach and resist any change in policy wrt Syrians already in Germany (Linke in Germany has called such move contemptible) when the situation is safe.  If you want to uphold refugee rights, which are not universally popular, to say the least, then best to be able to convince the electorate that such acceptance is not necessarily permanent.
